# how to javascript data validation by cypress?

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, cypress

I have a list,  which lists getting from javascript.  How to verify the javascript data by cypress.  I am trying to automate a project.  Attached are the features screenshot.
how-to javascript data validation by cypress?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly assert any of the continents directly using `eq` -

```js
cy.get('.location-selector ul li a').eq(0).should('have.text', 'North America')
cy.get('.location-selector ul li a').eq(1).should('have.text', 'South America')
```

And if you want to assert all the continents, you can also use a `each` and validate -

```js
var continents = [
  'North America',
  'South America',
  'Europe',
  'Asia',
  'Australia/NZ',
  'Middle East/Africa',
]

cy.get('.location-selector ul li a').each(($ele, index) => {
  expect($ele.text().trim()).to.equal(continents[index])
})
```

Comment: Did not work this solution

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: Hello
I have 7 tabs. In each tab have a list.  I have to verify this list. 
 Error screenshot:  https://prnt.sc/1vtz6ae
Functionality video:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/c8soecl1fqmhmu5/video.wmv?dl=0 

Thank You

Comment: Updated the answer with new locator. You can check now.

Comment: Thank you for your solution.  it's working but getting a minimum error for the last tab execution  
Screenshot:  https://prnt.sc/1vu8afj

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, replace `Middle East/Africa`  from the continents array with text that was displayed in the 'was' part of the error with the new line character`\n`. It could be  `\nMiddle East/Africa` or `\n Middle East/Africa` or a better way would be to copy from the error itself.

Comment: AssertionError
expected '<a.js-tab-links>' to have text '\n Middle East/Africa', but the text was '\n                                Middle East/Africa'

Comment: I have updated my answer. It seems like there is some extra space `Middle East/Africa` coming, so now I have trimmed those. Can you try now.

Answer (score 2):

The test should generally follow the way you'd manually test the page, for example on first loading "North America" is the active page, so test that link is active.

Then test the content is correct, both titles and images, after that moving on to other tabs.

An example,

```js
cy.visit('https://my-vacation.com/home')

cy.contains('a.js-tab-links', 'North America')
  .should('have.class', 'active')                  // this link is active after loading

// Titles on the page
cy.contains('Galveston Vacation Rentals')
cy.contains('Sedona Vacation Rentals')
//  ... same for remaining titles

// Images on the page
cy.get('img[src="galveston-island-historic-pleasure-pier.jpg"]')
// ... same for other images


// Other tabs
cy.contains('a.js-tab-links', 'South America')
  .click()                                      // activate this tab
  .should('have.class', 'active')

// Titles on the page
cy.contains('Peru Vacation Rentals')
cy.contains('Argentina Vacation Rentals')
//  ... same for remaining titles

// Images on the page
cy.get('img[src="machu-pichu.jpg"]')
// ... same for other images
```

You can break it up so that each section has it's own test

```js
before(() => {
  cy.visit('my-vacation.html')  // visit once before all the tests
})

it('North America', () => {
  cy.contains('a.js-tab-links', 'North America')
    .should('have.class', 'active')                  // this link is active after loading

  // Titles on the page
  cy.contains('Galveston Vacation Rentals')
  cy.contains('Sedona Vacation Rentals')
  //  ... same for remaining titles

  // Images on the page
  cy.get('img[src="galveston-island-historic-pleasure-pier.jpg"]')
  // ... same for other images
})

it('South America', () => {
  cy.contains('a.js-tab-links', 'South America')
    .click()                                      // activate this tab
    .should('have.class', 'active')

  // Titles on the page
  cy.contains('Peru Vacation Rentals')
  cy.contains('Argentina Vacation Rentals')
  //  ... same for remaining titles

  // Images on the page
  cy.get('img[src="machu-pichu.jpg"]')
  // ... same for other images
})
```

Comment: Did not work this solution